# Return a list by a POST Request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django and python, I want to return all the objects having the foreign key provided by a post request.

this is my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    isFavorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this is my serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image', 'price', 'isFavorite')
```

this is my code in views.py:

```
class ListProductsOfCategory(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # catch the category id of the products.
        category_id = request.data.get("category_id", "")
        # check if category id not null
        if not category_id:
            """

            Do action here 

            """
        # check if category with this id exists     
        if not Category.objects.filter(id=category_id).exists():
            """

            Do action here 

            """

        selected_category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
        # get products of this provided category.
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=selected_category)
        serialized_products = []
        # serialize to json all product fetched 
        for product in products:
            serializer = ProductSerializer(data={
                "id": product.id,
                "name": product.name,
                "image": product.image,
                "price": product.price,
                "isFavorite": product.isFavorite
            })
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                serialized_products.append(serializer.data)
            else:
                return
        return Response(
            data=serialized_products
            ,
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

this code partially worked, its returning the below reponse.

[image]

the problem is that the primary key "id" of the product is missing, I want the response to be like that :

[image]

P.S. If anyone can enhance the code and make it less complex I'd be grateful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the serializers the wrong way round. You should pass in the instance and it will give you the serialized data; passing in the data and checking is_valid is for submitting data, not sending it. Also, you can pass in the whole queryset with `many=True`:

```
serialized_products = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
```

so you don't need your for loop.

But actually DRF will even do all of this for you, because you are using a ListAPIView. All you need to do is tell it what queryset you want, which you do in the `get_queryset` method. So all you need is:

```
class ListProductsOfCategory(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category__id=self.request.data['category_id'])
```

Comment: there still remains one problem, and it's that I want this to be a Post Request, 
If I tired the above solution as a post request, it's returning that Post method is not allowed, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: sorry but can you help me with the post issue ?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a post? That method is for sending data, not receiving it.

Comment: I'm providing a category id

Comment: So why can't you provide that in the GET data?

Comment: you're right, I'm sorry for wasting your time, I just thought about it I can provide the category Id in the url, I dont care if its secure or not.